# Password reset link not working showing expired

Tags: magento-1.9, password, password-recovery

When I'm trying to reset password through reset link from my mail, it's showing following error:

> Your password reset link has expired.

When I check my password reset link it looks like:

> http://example.com/index.php/customer/account/resetpassword/?id=327

the reset password token is not generating I've checked the reset password template and it's looking fine:

```
<a href="{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}"><span>Reset Password</span></a>
```

and I didn't update anything in my AccountController.php

```
public function changeForgottenAction()
{
    try {
        list($customerId, $resetPasswordLinkToken) = $this->_getRestorePasswordParameters($this->_getSession());
        $this->_validateResetPasswordLinkToken($customerId, $resetPasswordLinkToken);
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        Mage::log($exception);
        $this->_getSession()->addError($this->_getHelper('customer')->__('Your password reset link has expired.'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have experience the same thing. Did you find a solution?

Comment: You are missing the password reset token in your url, see my solution.
It should show something similar to this: `customer/account/resetpassword/?id=585&token=941a6fad20d128b4e04cbab260060b19`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do some digging, as seen the `catch (Exception $e){}` method catches **any** exception and outputs that message.

Try logging the exception:

```
Mage::log($e, null, 'customer_password_reset.log');
```

Then you can inspect the log file & identify what is causing the issue & figure out how to resolve it.

Comment: I am new to php, how can i apply catch (Exception $e){} into my code and how to find the issue? could you pls help me to find out the error?@Moose

Answer (score 0):

It can be related to a template file. I experienced the same error when i tried to update my password.

Try to replace the following in: `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml`

Before:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/resetpasswordpost'); ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
```

After:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/resetpasswordpost', array('_query' => array('id' => $this->getCustomerId(), 'token' => $this->getResetPasswordLinkToken()))); ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
```

After you changed it please try again.

Comment: overwriting core files is very dangerous during magento upgrade right?   @Frank Groot

Comment: @Gem Yes that's true those edits will get overwritten while upgrading

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use **old email templates**:

Replace

`{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}`
with

`{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/" _query_id=$customer.rp_customer_id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}`