# 1.9 - Customers getting password link expired - no customer ID in URL

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, password-recovery

My customers have recently started getting the "Your password link has expired." message upon clicking the reset link in their email.

The settings are correct, I have expiration links set to expire after an hour. I recently updated to 1.9.4.0, however I'm unsure if this started then or after I opened a new website for my shop and started sharing customers globally. It was only reported to me recently, after upgrading though.

I'm logging exceptions, as suggested here: [Password reset link not working showing expired](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109112/password-reset-link-not-working-showing-expired)

I get this:

```
2018-12-19T22:00:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): Mage_Core_Exception Object
(
    [_messages:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[message:protected] => Invalid password reset token.
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 0
[file:protected] => /home/website/public_html/app/Mage.php
[line:protected] => 583
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
                [line] => 902
                [function] => exception
                [class] => Mage
                [type] => ::
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Mage_Core
                        [1] => Invalid password reset token.
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
                [line] => 813
                [function] => _validateResetPasswordLinkToken
                [class] => Mage_Customer_AccountController
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                        [1] => 732a0a17e38c2a2f28b65267301f09e7
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php
                [line] => 418
                [function] => resetPasswordAction
                [class] => Mage_Customer_AccountController
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
                [line] => 254
                [function] => dispatch
                [class] => Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => resetpassword
                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/public_html/app/code/community/Folio3/MaintenanceMode/Controller/Router/Standard.php
                [line] => 43
                [function] => match
                [class] => Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http Object
                            (
                                [_originalPathInfo:protected] => /customer/account/resetpassword/
                                [_storeCode:protected] => default
                                [_requestString:protected] => /customer/account/resetpassword/
                                [_rewritedPathInfo:protected] => 
                                [_requestedRouteName:protected] => 
                                [_routingInfo:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                                [_route:protected] => customer
                                [_directFrontNames:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                        [api] => 
                                    )

                                [_controllerModule:protected] => Diglin_Username
                                [_isStraight:protected] => 
                                [_beforeForwardInfo:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                                [_internallyForwarded:protected] => 
                                [_paramSources:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => _GET
                                        [1] => _POST
                                    )

                                [_requestUri:protected] => /customer/account/resetpassword/\?token=732a0a17e38c2a2f28b65267301f09e7
                                [_baseUrl:protected] => 
                                [_basePath:protected] => 
                                [_pathInfo:protected] => /customer/account/resetpassword/
                                [_params:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                                [_rawBody:protected] => 
                                [_aliases:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                                [_dispatched:protected] => 1
                                [_module:protected] => customer
                                [_moduleKey:protected] => module
                                [_controller:protected] => account
                                [_controllerKey:protected] => controller
                                [_action:protected] => resetpassword
                                [_actionKey:protected] => action
                            )

                    )

            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php
                [line] => 172
                [function] => match
                [class] => Folio3_MaintenanceMode_Controller_Router_Standard
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http Object
                            (
                                [_originalPathInfo:protected] => /customer/account/resetpassword/
                                [_storeCode:protected] => default
                                [_requestString:protected] => /customer/account/resetpassword/
                                [_rewritedPathInfo:protected] => 
                                [_requestedRouteName:protected] => 
                                [_routingInfo:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                                [_route:protected] => customer
                                [_directFrontNames:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                        [api] => 
                                    )

                                [_controllerModule:protected] => Diglin_Username
                                [_isStraight:protected] => 
                                [_beforeForwardInfo:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                                [_internallyForwarded:protected] => 
                                [_paramSources:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => _GET
                                        [1] => _POST
                                    )

                                [_requestUri:protected] => /customer/account/resetpassword/\?token=732a0a17e38c2a2f28b65267301f09e7
                                [_baseUrl:protected] => 
                                [_basePath:protected] => 
                                [_pathInfo:protected] => /customer/account/resetpassword/
                                [_params:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                                [_rawBody:protected] => 
                                [_aliases:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                                [_dispatched:protected] => 1
                                [_module:protected] => customer
                                [_moduleKey:protected] => module
                                [_controller:protected] => account
                                [_controllerKey:protected] => controller
                                [_action:protected] => resetpassword
                                [_actionKey:protected] => action
                            )

                    )

            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                [line] => 365
                [function] => dispatch
                [class] => Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/public_html/app/Mage.php
                [line] => 687
                [function] => run
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [scope_code] => base
                                [scope_type] => website
                                [options] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/website/public_html/index.php
                [line] => 97
                [function] => run
                [class] => Mage
                [type] => ::
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => base
                        [1] => website
                    )

            )

    )

[previous:Exception:private] =>
```

)

I'm not getting any other errors in `exception.log` that have to do with it.

**Update 1/2/2019**
After finding some time to come back to this issue, I've found that the customer ID isn't being added to the reset URL.  I think this issue may have started around when I opened up a second store/website, however, I do in fact have customers shared globally.

I've done some additional testing and can confirm that the ID is being successfully grabbed from the form post. So the issue is that it's not being passed to the URL given in the email.

What the email password reset link looks like:
`www.example.net/customer/account/resetpassword/?token=3f042b9d36e64ea135d778cd5c7eed64`

clearly missing the `id=xxx?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after viewing the email template, it turns out it was the culprit but I don't really know why. I mean, I know why, but I don't understand why it **only just now** broke.

Original code:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="action-button" >
     <tr>
         <td>
              <a href="{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}"><span>Reset Password</span></a>
         </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Fixed code:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="action-button" >
     <tr>
         <td>
              <a href='{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}'><span>Reset Password</span></a>
         </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

The nested quotations were causing the issue, so I simply changed the outside double quotations to single quotations.

Comment: Still my error continues, may i know is there any issue related with reset password error? @taskle

Comment: I haven’t had any issues since I fixed the email template. Have you checked for errors and made sure the tokens are being correctly passed from the form? @Gem

Comment: For me, the reset password mail send to customer mail,, if click reset password link the page shows your link expired, any idea about this error? @taskle

Comment: That’s what was happening for me as well. Test the reset yourself and check the URL of the link contained in the reset email. Make sure it contains the customer ID, as well as the token.

Comment: Yes, mail reset link contains id and token,, id=12&token=94ae10098fb93f20feff8cb66c72d355, what i need to do in next level @taskle

Comment: Have you tried checking the logs for any error? How much time do you have set before the link expires? It might not be something simple like mine was, so I would be sure to check your exception log for anything out of the ordinary. I know some people fixed it by changing the template code after a Magento update